# Sort by vote in the last X period?

Tags: feature-request, voting, sorting

As it is today, sorting by vote is largely useless since it allows only to see the all time highest or lowest votes.

I propose to copy another feature from reddit and have add a "last hour", "last day", "last week" "all time" choice to it.

Comment: I like the idea, but where exactly would this choice go? The other choices like "Newest" and "Featured" etc. work with only one click. Adding an extra filter would either require extra clicks (but where?), or extra buttons (which is just messy)

Comment: Have you tried the "Hot" tab?

Comment: Could probably be provided by a greasemonkey script if it's not implemented natively.

Answer (score 1):

Good idea.

I think it would also be useful to have a couple of boxes on the side to specify a date range in case those presets aren't accurate enough.

Answer (score 0):

This would only be useful for those questions which have more than a few answers.

In other words, discussion, polling, or very subjective questions.

SO Q&A format doesn't really support discussion style questions, and so encouraging them by providing better support for reading them is not likely.

If you can give a few examples of great SO questions that really would be *much better* with this functionality, it would go a long way toward convincing the powers that be that this feature is necessary.

Comment: My main point is that the feature as it is today is useless and that would make it somehow more useful. If you don't agree with that there is noting much I can do about it.